# Sort hibernate collection when retrieving from database

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an object Foo with a list of Bar.  Is there a way I can set up my class so that getBars() will return a List that has been sorted with Collections.sort?  In other words, I would like to run Collections.sort when the list is first populated.  Presently, I call sort when I retrieve the collection, which may be redundant and is easily forgotten.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Are you using J2EE-style mappings with Hibernate XML files, or are you using JPA-annotated JavaBeans?

If you're using JPA, you can use the [`@OrderBy`](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/index.html#entity-mapping-association-collections) annotation to let the database sort the collection for you. You could also use [`@Sort`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-sorted) to do it on the Java side.

Last, if you're writing HQL - say, in a `@NamedQuery` - you can use the [`ORDER BY`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-ordering) clause.

Lots of ways to do it!

Answer (score 7):

I think if you annotate the property with `@Sort` it gets sorted automatically

You've also got the option to specify a custom [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) class:

```
@Sort(comparator=MyComparator.class, type=SortType.COMPARATOR)
```

**Reference:**

- [`@Sort` javadocs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/annotations/Sort.html)
- [Hibernate Reference: Sorted
  Collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-sorted)

Comment: Just a head's up the `@Sort` annotation has been deprecated, an updated example would look like this: `@SortComparator(MyComparator.class)`.

Comment: @JasonSperske why don't you add an answer with that?

Answer (score 3):

check out the hibernate docs on sorted collections

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-sorted.

You can also put another method in your DAO that uses hql to fetch the children, which you can sort via hql.

If the sorting procedure is not based off a single column, I don't think you have any choice but to do the sort yourself. You can add the logic to your domain model...

Answer (score 3):

If you are using XML configuration, you can set `order-by` attribute:-

```
<class name="Foo" table="Foo">
    ...

    <set name="bars" inverse="true" order-by="barName">
        <key column="fooId" />
        <one-to-many class="Bar" />
    </set>
</class>
```

This way, when you invoke `foo.getBars()`, you will get `Bar` objects ordered by bar name, in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the list when you select from the DB would be a better (let db sort it) choice instead of sorting it after selecting.

Comment: Sure, but it's not an option when you want to sort a collection of a Criteria query.

Comment: Are you merging different query results into one and then sorting what you have?